# mouseup listener in angular 5

Tags: angular, listener

How can I achieve this jquery

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $("#post-emoji-picker");
    // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        container.hide();
        this.toggled = false; //angular didn't compile this
    }
});
```

to angular event listener

Comment: you can use https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#host to add an event listener

Comment: Maybe `e => {` instead of `function (e) {` will work, but as suggested you should use host listener

Answer (score 3):

Add a global event target like

```
<div (window:mousedown)="mouseDown()" (window:mouseup)="mouseUp()"></div>
```

to listen to events globally. (body and document work as well).

This works of course also in the components class

```
@HostListener('window:mouseup', ['$event'])
mouseUp(event){}
```

Comment: you can also add the `host` to the `@Component()`